# Is there a way to find the sum and the cumulative count in this MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum, window-functions

I have this MYSQL query i'm using to find the cumulative growth of a table `groups` in its associated table `members` over time.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT g.name, m.created_at,
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION by g.id ORDER BY m.created_at) count
    FROM members m
    INNER JOIN groups g on g.id = m.group_id
```

This gives a result set like:

```
[
  { 'group01', date: '2019-03-04', count: 5 },
  { 'group01', date: '2019-03-09', count: 12 }
  { 'group01', date: '2019-03-15', count: 23 }
  { 'group02', date: '2019-03-04', count: 3 }
  { 'group01', date: '2019-03-10', count: 19 }
  { 'group01', date: '2019-03-17', count: 27 }
]
```

I would also to retrieve the total count of a groups members as well. Such that the data set would look like:

```
[
  { name: 'group01', date: '2019-03-04', count: 5, total: 23 },
  { name: 'group01', date: '2019-03-09', count: 12, total: 23 },
  { name: 'group01', date: '2019-03-15', count: 23, total: 23 },
  { name: 'group02', date: '2019-03-04', count: 3, total: 27 },
  { name: 'group02', date: '2019-03-10', count: 19, total: 27 },
  { name: 'group02', date: '2019-03-17', count: 27, total: 27 }
]
```

I need to do this so that at a later point i can easily order & find the top  groups in terms of members.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please show us your current results, and your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another column to the resultset, that does a window count over the same `partition` but without an `order by` clause; this causes the database to compute the total number of rows in the partition:

```
SELECT g.name, m.created_at,
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION by g.id ORDER BY m.created_at) count,
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION by g.id) total
FROM members m
INNER JOIN groups g on g.id = m.group_id
```

Note: I am suspicious about the use of `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` clause, so I removed it (it rarely makes sense to use that along with window functions, although there are edge cases) - you can add it back if needed.

Comment: This works. I just dont see how one would know intuitively that ordering would cause window queries to compute the total in the row. My understanding is the entire point of window queries was that you get individual rows back, it seems like a bit of arbitrary behavior? I do distinct because in the full query, i round the datetime values to the day & that causes the query to return double values.

Comment: @Matthey . . . I don't think this really does what you want.  If I understand correctly, it returns multiple rows per group/date.  I recommend `GROUP BY` for your problem (which is why I answered).

Answer (score 0):

I would write this with explicit aggregation:

```
SELECT g.name, m.created_at,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY g.id ORDER BY m.created_at) as count_on_day,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY g.id) as count_for_group
FROM members m INNER JOIN
     groups g 
     ON g.id = m.group_id
GROUP BY g.name, m.created_at
```